# How Do I Make My Stack Based Calculator Successfully Print The Polish Notation Of Several Numbers Added Together In Succession?

Tags: java

I've been banging my head against this for a couple of nights and I just can't get it. I've solved all cases but one. When my program prints the REVERSE polish notation of problems like 2+5*8 it comes out to:

```
5 8 40  * +
```

Where it should be 5 8 2 * +. I was hoping someone could give me some insight to why my program is not working how I want it to - the program correctly solves the problem!

```
public static void evaluateTop(Stack<Integer> num, char op) {
    characters += op + " ";
    if (num.size() == 0) {
        error("Syntax error");
    }
    int y = num.pop();
    if (num.size() == 0) {
        error("Syntax error");
    }
    int x = num.pop();
    int z = 0;
    if (op == '*') {
        z = x * y;
    } else if (op == '/') {
        if (y == 0) {
            error("Divide by 0");
        } else {
            z = x / y;
        }
    } else if (op == '+') {
        z = x + y;
    } else if (op == '-') {
        z = x - y;
    } else {
        error("Syntax error");
    }
    char checker = characters.charAt(characters.length() - 1);
    if (isVirgin) {
        numbers += x + " ";
        numbers += y + " ";
    } else if ((op == '*' || op == '/') && (checker != '+' && checker != '-')) {
        numbers += y + " ";
    } else {
        numbers += x + " ";
    }
    num.push(z);
}
```

Comment: If your current output does not match your desired output, and you don't know why, then it's time to start debugging. If you're not sure how to go about doing this, then please check out [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). It won't solve your direct problem, but it will give you steps that you can follow that should help you solve it yourself, or even if that is not successful, then at least help you to better isolate your problem so that your question can be more focused and easier to answer.

Comment: The expected output you gave looks like [reverse polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation), and not the [polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation) you mentioned above. Please figure out what you're really trying to do.

Comment: Sorry, I meant RPN